# Rails application ignores RAILS_ENV=production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We've done `export RAILS_ENV=development`. But still, the app uses the `production` values from `database.yml`. It is as if no matter what we do, `production` is always enforced. Where is this done and how do we kill it?

Comment: are you running it in local environment? Also what command are you using to run the server. Please provide more information.

Comment: We use rails start to run it locally, yes. Latest version of spree, latest version of rails.

Comment: `rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development` did you try to use this command to start the server?